# While iterating is it faster to call an array's length attribute twice or to make a new variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I am curious if it is faster to call an array's length attribute twice while iterating through it, or to make a new variable.

**Example of calling length attribute:**

```
private void addColumns() {

   for( int i = 0; i < puzzleArr.length; i++ ) {

      char[] column = new char[puzzleArr[i].length];

      for( int j = 0; j < puzzleArr[i].length; j++ ) {
         // do something
      }
   }

}
```

**Example of making a new variable:**

```
private void addColumns() {

   for( int i = 0; i < puzzleArr.length; i++ ) {
      int arrayLength = puzzleArr[i].length;

      char[] column = new char[arrayLength];

      for( int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++ ) {
         // do something
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Take an example of C language. When you define a record , you add few attributes/field and those can be accesed in constant time. Same way, think of java defining an array as struct with a length field in it.

Comment: @KhanSaab - that kind of misses the point.  Both `array.length` and accessing a variable are `O(1)` ... but that doesn't mean that the constant of proportionality is the same in all cases.  See the linked Q&A for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @StephenC how can one mention the constants with Big-O notation? I see very few people using tilde notation and i prefer that but not everyone knows about that.

Comment: My point is that you are ignoring the constants!  You say *"can be accessed in constant time"*, but ignore the fact that the constants are different.  Even in C, accessing a field of a `struct` and a variable don't necessarily take the same time.